# failed to get ec2 instance public ip on instance startup (windows)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I tried the below powershell script on startup (passed it as a user data):

```
<powershell>

$instancePublicIp = (wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4).Content
while ($instancePublicIp.length -eq 0) 
{
Start-Sleep -s 40
$instancePublicIp = (wget http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4).Content
Add-Content c:\debug.txt "public ip : $($instancePublicIp) - "
}



</powershell>
```

I verified the script is running because debug.txt exists on C: drive. but the public ip comes back empty. 
I also tried sleeping for 40 seconds to allow the instance to start and the network adapter is connected with no luck.

the same script above runs and gives back proper ip address when running it manually though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you launching your instance in public subnet? Is auto-assign-public-ip enabled for your subnet?

Comment: Does it matter? I can get the public ip by querying the instance-data service manually right? @helloV

Comment: @helloV and yes auto assign is enabled.

Comment: I am not familiar with powershell. But if the AWS dashboard shows a public IP assigned to your windows instance, then you should be able to retrive it using metadata server. Or open a command window in your windows machine (though RDP) and execute the same powershell script and see it works. Then you know how to debug this.

Comment: it works from other ec2 instances, and it works on the same instance. The only time it does not work is when I run it on startup which i don't understand why. @helloV